# @remix-run/node & Cloudflare page

Tags: node.js, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers, remix.run, cloudflare-pages

I'm using cloudflare page template and I don't import @remix-run/node anywhere.
Also package.json file doesn't involve @remix-run/node
But after yarn install, @remix-run/node is created and when I try to compile then an error occurs.

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "fs/promises"

```
node_modules/@remix-run/node/upload/fileUploadHandler.js:17:23:
  17 │ var promises = require('fs/promises');
     ╵                        ~~~~~
```

The package "fs/promises" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node. Are you trying to bundle for node? You can use "platform: 'node'" to do that, which will remove this error.
How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score -4):

Encountered this myself, trying this

https://reactjsexample.com/an-example-of-prisma-working-on-cloudflare-pages-with-remix/